# How to get the orientation of a street on Android Google Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to display cars on a map in my Android app. I'd like the car to be oriented the same as the street, so it looks like it's riding in the street. I can't find a way to do that. Is there a way?

Comment: google does not provide street data in google maps. do you perhaps get real time lat/lng from these cars?

Comment: crazy idea : your car on the street and you know the street name. if you ask geolocation for this street google sends coordinates of middle point in the street. line between your coordinates and middle point is dirrectional vector. yep street can be curve but this method can give you approximate angle

Comment: another crazy idea is to get route between your position and middle of street than interval of route nearest to you will define direction . or if you already have route on your map you can get nearest interval from it

Comment: I have lat long for the cars. I was thinking of getting the route to a certain point, then the start of the route should give me the initial orientation. But that's cumbersome, especially if you want to put a coupld dozen cars on the map. I thought maybe there's a simple solution :-)
Thanks for the replies anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found one possible solution in the "snap to road" API. I'm thinking of generating a location 10 or 20 meters away from the car, then see where it snaps, that should give me a heading that's accurate enough.

Comment: seeing that you are getting locations from a source you have no control over this is going to be your best solution then